# How to display in the CP only the current user's entries?

Tags: users, control-panel, admin

Well the issue is simple, I have a multi-user backoffice, where they use the same section and entry type to create a new entry.  The problem is when the current user (not the admin) tries to add an entry in the entries field, it display the list of all other users entries, but this is not the case when viewing the section from the dashboard.  The current user (except for the admin who sees all) only sees his own entries. Can I somehow make the entry field display the current user's only list of entries to chose from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Craft currently doesn't have the concept of "read" permissions for elements (entries, tags, categories, etc.)... technically any user that has access to the Control Panel has read access to every Craft element whether there is a nice UI way to access them or not.

Feel free to comment/vote on this feature request though, which would enable what you're looking for: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/887

Comment: I hope at least in Craft 3 won't be the case ...

Comment: Still the same in 3.0.  Unlikely it'd make it into 3.x as it'd probably fit into this larger permissions refactoring: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1646  That likely wouldn't happen until Craft 4 since it'd be a breaking change.